# Saving and retrieving custom objects in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsdata

It's the first time I'm trying to save and retrieve custom data to/from my core data, but I've run into an error saying:

> fatal error: array cannot be bridged from Objective-C

when I try to load the data back.

My code looks like this, the arrayOfNames is declared as `[String]`:

```
@IBAction func saveTap(sender: AnyObject) {

    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let contxt: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Indexes", inManagedObjectContext: contxt)


    let arrayData: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(arrayOfNames)

    let newIndex = Indexes(entity: en!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)
    newIndex.monday = arrayData

    println(newIndex.monday)

    contxt.save(nil)

}

@IBAction func loadTap(sender: AnyObject) {

    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    let fetchReq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Indexes")
    let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Indexes", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    var myList:[String] = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchReq, error: nil) as! [String]

    println(myList)

}
```

My model-file looks like this:

```
@objc(Indexes)
class Indexes: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var monday: NSData
    @NSManaged var tuesday: NSData
    @NSManaged var wednesday: NSData
    @NSManaged var thursday: NSData
    @NSManaged var friday: NSData
}
```

I've also set all the attributes to `transformable` in my data model. As I said, it's the first time I'm doing this, so sorry if the solution is obvious.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`executeFetchRequest` returns `[AnyObject]?`, not `[String]`, indeed the objects in the array should be `Indexes` instances which contain your archived arrays of strings.

So, you need to correct the array type that the results of the fetch are being placed into.